# Could use a bit of XAML guidance when designing with ESRI Silverlight Viewer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I'm trying to implement a version of **[this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm#MapExtent)** in my web map:

As you can see, part of the XAML is:

```
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" WrapAround="True" ExtentChanged="MyMap_ExtentChanged" ExtentChanging="MyMap_ExtentChanged">
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="StreetMapLayer" 
            Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
    </esri:Map>
```

For me, the problem lies in that I'm trying to create a new widget that will show this information in a little window that pops up when someone opens it. The layers are defined elsewhere in the project (in an AppConfig.xml file), I don't need to create a new map in this widget. I just want something that can get the extents that the user is zoomed into. That's what I don't know how to do... I'm not sure how to get that information if I'm not defining the map layers in that particular XAML file I created for the widget.

I apologize if there's some really easy answer. I've been working on this web map stuff for only a couple weeks and I run into this type of issue a lot, where sample code is shown defining layers and going from there... but it's not necessarily transferable to designing with widgets. Or maybe it is, and I'm just a complete newbie to Silverlight, C# and XAML :(.

Oh, and I'm working on adding a widget to **[this](http://vertisee.mcelhanney.com/Apps/MapsByAir_public/)**.  It'll just go next to the Print one =).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Map object to your own UserControl and handling ExtentChanged event programmably. Here is the sample code.

```
public partial class SilverlightControl1 : UserControl {

    private Map _map;

    public SilverlightControl1(Map map) {

        InitializeComponent();

        _map = map;

        //handling ExtentChanged event
        _map.ExtentChanged += _map_ExtentChanged;
    }

    public ~SilverlightControl1() {

        if (_map != null) {

            _map.ExtentChanged -= _map_ExtentChanged;
        }
    }

    void _map_ExtentChanged(object sender, ExtentEventArgs e) {

        //Update label text
        lblXmin.Content = e.NewExtent.XMin;
        lblYmin.Content = e.NewExtent.YMin;

        //....
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of your use case (please elaborate if I'm off base here), but in the Viewer, you can get the extent the user is zoomed to as follows:

```
Envelope currentExtent = MapApplication.Current.Map.Extent;
```

Also, there's a sample for the Silverlight Viewer that's very similar to the one you linked to (which is for the API, not the Viewer).  First go to the Silverlight Viewer's interactive samples app at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-viewer/samples/start.html. Then select Map --> Show Map Extent from the list to the left of the map.